# Create Admin Only Taxonomies?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, wp-admin

Is there a way to create admin-only taxonomies in wordpress?

I have some things I'd like to tag with private, admin-only terms (for various reasons.) Is there a way to do this?

**EDIT**: Use case: I don't want the taxonomy or their terms getting their own url. i.e site.com/taxonomy/term

I also don't want the terms searchable on the frontend

Comment: What purpose would this serve? Filtering out specific terms for admins or non-admins doesn't sound performant or easy, but only registering a custom taxonomy if the user has admin privileges is trivial

Comment: I'd like to mostly keep them from getting their own url structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe when registering the taxonomy: setting `public` to false and `show_in_menu`, `show_in_nav_menus`, `show_ui` all to true would solve what I *THINK* is your request, without knowing any further what your use case is.

Comment: i read this as well. However, I'm looking to remove the taxonomy's from the url structure of wp. Just updated my question. Sorry for the lack of clarity.

Comment: You were right and my slug suppressing request was in the docs: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Example_Private_Taxonomy