# Private categories in Wordpress

Tags: categories, private

How can i create private category in Wordpress? What i mean? Authors can't see the category and can't add that category to their posts but admins and editors are can see that category and add the everyones posts. Such as: Editor's Picks category. How can we do that?

Note: I want to do that without plugins.

Comment: You will need a plugin for that. It's clearly [not theme code](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73031/where-to-put-my-code-plugin-or-functions-php), and where else should it go?

Comment: Sorry, i was not clear. I dont want to use third party plugin.

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/

Comment: This link is not an answer to your question, but the use case you mention suggests that it would be better to have a private taxonomy for this: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/218082/create-admin-only-taxonomies